# Tailwind CSS partially working in NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am creating a NextJS Blog. Tailwind CSS is working properly except in the following case.

```js
export default async function PostPage({ params }) {
  ...
  const tags = post.data.tags.split(',').map(tag => `<span className="bg-red-600 m-2">${tag}</span>`).join('').toString(); // post.data.tags = "abc, pqr, xyz"
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl mt-4 mb-0">{post.data.title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tags }} />
    </>
  )
}
```

If you see at the `span` element, it has some CSS. It's not working. However, `h1` is working fine. If I add some css to `p` element, it works as well. I am new to NextJS. How to solve this?

Comment: Consider checking the file is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: Aside from your question: Why do you create string and insert it instead of using jsx?

Comment: @Wongjn ```content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ]``` I do not know what to check here?

Comment: @Konrad It works same without string and with jsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `className="bg-red-600 m-2"`, use `class="bg-red-600 m-2"`

**className** is used for React, not raw HTML which you are using inside **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML: An object of the form { __html: '<p>some
> html</p>' } with a **raw HTML** string inside.

Source: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#common-props